# jQuery fadein fadeout effects in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I am making an app using Cordova and it uses jQuery effects namely fadein and fadeout. The effects are very slow on my android device. I thought of converting them to CSS and I saw ways to do that using toggleClass etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            $( "#fade" ).click(function() {
                $('#fader').toggleClass('fadeout');
            });
            $('#fader').on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
                $('#fader').toggleClass('hide');
            });
            setTimeout(500)
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        div{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        #fader{
            display: block;
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s linear;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s linear;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.35s linear;
            -o-transition: opacity 0.35s linear;
            transition: opacity 0.35s linear;
        }
        #fader.fadeout{
            opacity: 0;
        }
        #fader.fadeout.hide{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fader">
        css
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="fade">
        DivButton
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I encountered two issues:

Issue 1

While using jQuery fadein, in the end it sets display to none. Similarly while using fadeout, it removes the display:none property. Also the animations are abrupt. How can I do that in CSS?

Issue 2

I would like to use delay function along with the fadein and fadeout in CSS. How can I achieve that?

Please help guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be nice if you can provide the code or a JSFiddle example.. Anyway, you can probably do that using class toggle which fades the element using `opacity` and you can set the delay and transition time in the css `transition` property. As for `display:none` it cannot be "animated" and having it can give weird results, try playing with `visibility:none`

Comment: I have already seen those examples using toggleClass.. But there are none with the visibility. And also.. I don't know how to play with visibility

Comment: All right, please share the code or a demo so we can have a better look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `display:none;` will remove the block abruptly, so you might want to animate the height as well.

Below is an example of the CSS transition:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".toggle-fade").click(function() {
        $(".block").toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

```css
.block {
    background:red;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition:2s;
    -webkit-transition:2s;
    transition-delay:1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:1s;
}
.block.hidden {
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0px;
    opacity:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    
</div>
<button class="toggle-fade">Toggle block</button>
```

[Fiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/kd0jnxLd/)

Comment: @Johann Yes you can. However I also added a delay to the CSS itself. When do you want the delay to happen? You can add it here if you want: `$(".block").delay(1000).toggleClass('hidden')`